# What does heroes bind to inside of the service which uses the method .subscribe?

Tags: angular

I've not been able to figure out what heroes is binding to inside of the subscribe method. When I get rid of the heroes type, somehow it is still displaying all of my heroes on the page. So if heroes has nothing to bind to inside of the service, how is it still able to display my heroes?

The following is the component that houses the subscribe method:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[];

selectedHero: Hero;

onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}

getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}

constructor(private heroService : HeroService) {}


 ngOnInit() { 
    this.getHeroes();
  }

}
```

And this is the hero service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './heroes/hero';
import { HEROES } from './heroes/mock.heroes';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

So here is the strange part: if you delete

```
heroes: Hero[];
```

The heroes still get displayed. How is that possible if there is nothing for the subscribe method to bind into? If the subscribe method is not binding into heroes, then how is heroes getting displayed onto the page?

All of the code has been done up to *Subscribe in HeroesComponent* in the tutorial of heroes @ https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent

Comment: if you are referring to the subscription call on the getHeroes() method of the service "HeroService". Have a look at the ```return of(HEROES)```.

Comment: I am referring to the heroes parameter inside of the subscribe method. I am not sure how my heroes are getting displayed if I am able to delete heroes entirely from the code and they still appear. What is heroes being assigned to exactly?

Answer (score 0):

your service method for fetching heroes :-

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }
```

If you deleted HEROES inside your service method then there wont be any heroe coming from any source.

Comment: Where is the service method being bound to on the heroes component? What is happening with this code: getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}

if when I delete heroes : Hero[] in the heroes component my heroes still get displayed.

Comment: Please check in template itself weather you are using  async pipe directly with subscription inside *ngFor loop.

Comment: <h2>My Heroes</h2>

<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>

That is the template.